# Some text are randomly colored in JavaFX WebView

Tags: java, html, intellij-idea, javafx, webview

I'm working on a project where I am using JavaFX's WebView and WebEngine to display HTML webpages. I have gotten it to display, but I am having a weird bug where some words are being colored randomly. It may be difficult to see, but here are screenshots of a few examples:

Parts of various words, like `unix` and `append`, appear purple:

[image: Parts of various words, like <code>unix</code> and <code>append</code>, appear purple]

I have looked at the HTML source files, and there are no tags or styling that can change their color. Opening it up in Firefox shows the text as completely normal, no random colors. Therefore, I believe that it only happens in the WebView. I tried this on another computer, and the issue occurs on it too.

Does anyone know what is happening? I can provide more description or parts of the code if necessary.

Edit:

Here is an example HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</body>
</html>
```

And this file is displayed with these lines of code:

```
String htmlFileURL = SearchToolWindowGUI.class.getResource("lorem.html").toExternalForm();

engine.load(htmlFileURL);
```

`engine` is an instance of `WebEngine`

I've discovered that this is only an issue when loading my own HTML file. If i were to do this:

`engine.load("http://www.lipsum.com")`, all coloring is normal.

Here is the example output:

[image: Examples are <code>leap</code> being green and <code>into</code> being purple]

Opening this HTML file in Firefox is completely normal.

Comment: Please, share some [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example] (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This looks quite a lot like your problem https://github.com/TomasMikula/RichTextFX/issues/145

Comment: @IvanPronin I have added an example with an image.

Comment: @litelite I will check out the link, thanks!

Comment: @litelite This does look similar but it appears that the issue was patched 2 years ago. I am on the latest version of Java and JavaFX.

Comment: Both images show anti-aliasing artifact.